# Send the local database data to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using coredata for saving my application data.if any changes in local coredata that will be notified while uploading the data to server.

If any user is edited any textfields means that will be saved in coredata, at that same time nothing is edited in the textfields then showing one alert message while entering viewcontroller.

*This is an image for expected output:*

[image: I will attach the image for expected my output]

Comment: Your question isn't understandable. Its not at all clear what it is you are asking.

Comment: @DonaldTrumpatemyhamster,Entering everytime in my application,if any changes happen in local data that will be upload to the server,if nothing is changed in data in my application, coredata should send an alert for no data change yet. This alert is not being shown right now. I m not sure what the problem is.